# AWK function to grab profiles for gnome-terminal

Tags: awk, grep

I want to be able to easily transport certain profiles of my gnome-terminal to another computer by using a sort of regex and filtering for the name. `grep` doesn't allow searching between newlines and I'm hoping `awk` (Technically `mawk` on Ubuntu) has that functionality. A profile looks like this:

```
[:c812de27-9bc9-414b-a263-4995c1ec775a]
background-color='rgb(31,36,40)'
palette=['rgb(106,115,125)', ...array of colors]
scroll-on-output=true
scrollbar-policy='never'
use-theme-colors=false
use-theme-transparency=false
visible-name='gh_dark'
```

These profiles are split by newlines when dumped via `dconf`

So far I've tried `grep`, but since that doesn't allow matching newlines (I found out after trying `grep "\[:.*\].*visible-name:'gh_dark'"`), I can't scope out several. I looked into the `-A` flag, but since there is no way to know how many lines a specific profile will be, it doesn't seem practical.

What I sort of want, given the name, is output like above where it is easy to see the full profile configuration

I want to know if there's a way to use `awk` to easily sort through these by grabbing the ids (at the top) along with the names to easily figure out which ones to export individually (which require ids) or just pull them out directly and place them in a file

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in your question along with sample expected output for better understanding of question, thank you.

Comment: Okay, thank you @RavinderSingh13

Comment: Thanks for adding your efforts, could you please confirm if you want to print output of a blog in your file when an entry for `visible-name='gh_dark'` is found? sorry but its not yet clear expected output.

Comment: Yes, when looking for `PROFILE_NAME` (in this case gh_dark), trigger output when finding `visible-name:'${PROFILE_NAME}'`

Comment: ok, could you please place more sample data why because if could see how to skip the non-matching block too, thank you.

Comment: Accepted answer is purely regex based so it is the right tag here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use GNU `grep` like so:

```
grep -Pzo '(?s)\[:.*?visible-name.*?\n' in_file
```

Here, `grep` uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-o` : Print the matches only (1 match per line), not the entire lines.
`-z` : Treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline. Thus, you can match newlines in the input.

`(?:s)` : Enable the `s` [pattern-match modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Extended-Patterns), to allow `.` to match a newline.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)
[perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Using `tac` + `awk` combination here. Since I had GNU `awk` so checked it on it, should work with mawk too I believe.

```
tac Input_file |
awk -v profileName="$profilename" '
match($0,"visible-name=\047" profileName "\047"){
  found=1
}
found;
/^\[:/{
  found=""
}' | tac
```

***Explanation:*** First `tac` will print the Input_file from bottom to up(reverse manner to make things easier for us in terms of comparison). Then program will pass `tac` output to `awk` program and shell variable named `profilename`(made your shell variable small letters which is always advised by experts), passed it to `awk` in its variable `profileName`. Then using `match` function of `awk` to match `visible-name='gh_dark` here if its found then setting found variable to here. ASAP found is set then printing the lines. Now where to stop printint the lines once a line found starting with `[:`(first line of your shown samples) then unset found.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `mawk` is posix compliant, this means that you can set the record separator to a blank. When doing that, it will split your input in records which are separated by one or more blank lines. This way you could quickly extract the profiles of interest.

Eg.

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=; ORS="\n\n"}
     /c812de27-9bc9-414b-a263-4995c1ec775a/
     /b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/
    ' input_file
```

This will print the configuration of two profiles.